# @vercel/postgres update query with multiple SET values

Tags: sql, postgresql, vercel

I started to use vercel yesterday with its `postgres` database service. Now I did use the npm package `mariadb` before, so I had to migrate. I am struggling with the update query in the following code.

```js
    let setValues = []

    setValues.push(user.name ? `name = "${twoWayEncrypt(user.name)}"` : undefined)
    setValues.push(user.email ? `email = "${twoWayEncrypt(user.email)}"` : undefined)
    setValues.push(
        user.password && user.password !== ''
            ? `password = "${await oneWayEncrypt(user.password)}"`
            : undefined,
    )
    setValues.push(
        user.access_rights ? `access_rights = '${JSON.stringify(user.access_rights)}'` : undefined,
    )

    setValues = setValues.filter(v => v)
    await sql`UPDATE users SET ${setValues.join(', ')} WHERE id = ${user.id};`
```

so what would be the appropriate way to create an update query as you can see below?

best regards